# How can I get Github release's tag_name via PHP?

Tags: php, github

I have try to use php to get Github release's tag_name,but in vain.
The link is [Latest Release](https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest)

```
<?php 

ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');
 $json =file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest") ;
 $myArray = json_decode($json);
 foreach( $myArray as $key => $value ){
     echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
 }
?>
```

Comment: You're pulling back an object, try setting the second `json_decode` argument with `true` to return it as an array.

Comment: @JonStirling like this? json_decode($json,true);

Comment: Yep, just like that.

Comment: Why not use `$myArray->tag_name` Why are people so afraid of objects. And maybe rename `$myArray` as `$myObj` to be more accurate

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am newbie in php...I will reedit my code to let it be better

Comment: @JonStirling is it possible to get github release tag_name without curl?

Comment: @RiggsFolly So it is not my server's problem? Because I am worry about it for three days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me. I had to set a stream context to get it to work

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest";
$opts = [
        'http' => [
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' => [
                        'User-Agent: PHP'
                ]
        ]
];

$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$json = file_get_contents( $url, 0, $ctx );

$myObj = json_decode($json);

echo 'The tag name is ' . $myObj->tag_name;
```

Result:

```
The tag name is 1.0.4
```

EDIT:

And then going back to your original code, this also worked

```
<?php
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');

$json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest") ;

$myObj = json_decode($json);

echo 'The tag name is ' . $myObj->tag_name;
```

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use? I try your code but it still doesn't work, I am using PHP 7.0.6, and my server is Virtual host..

Comment: I used 7.0.23, but let me check with 7.0.6

Comment: Using the Object notation that is, as in my EDIT code

Comment: I think this is my server's problem...I still get 504 error,may I see your test web site ?

Comment: I actually ran that from PHP CLI on my Windows PC no website involved

Comment: I got the point,my virtual host provider has block the out link function...

Answer (score 1):

try to extend the timeout duration

```
<?php 
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
 $json =file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest") ;
 //get a json not an array
 $myArray = json_decode($json,true);
 foreach( $myArray as $key => $value ){
     echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
 }
?>
```